# Determining order of AR model

Tags: matlab, autoregressive

Suppose that we have the following model
$$
y[t] = A_1\sin(\omega_1 t+\phi_1)+A_2\sin(\omega_2 t + \phi_2)+ \cdots  + A_p \sin(\omega_pt + \phi_p) + z(t) .
$$
Let us call this signal as B.
Then in matlab I  executed the following commands

```
>> [pxxr,fr]=pyulear(B,50,1024,100);
>> plot(fr,pxxr)
```

I get the following picture

[image]

It seems that order is correct, but I have done it using partial autocorrelation ploting.

I know that there are other criterias for determining AR order, like AIC, BIC, Minimum discription length (MDL), but how to calculate them in matlab?
Please help me with  code or  by some other criterias in matlab to determine order of AR model.

Comment: what i want to achieve is that have function which  for given signal,determine it's relevant AR order

Comment: There is an example for the AIC [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622600/how-can-i-apply-the-aic-criterion-to-time-series-data-using-matlab) that can be helpful.

Comment: but  how to apply it for given data?what is number of observation?

Comment: Did you look at the code? ... numObsv = length(dem2gbp);

Comment: what about number of  parameter?i have signal,what should be code for calculate AIC&BIC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `autocorr(B)` and `parcorr(B)` in MATLAB. You'll have to learn interpreting the graphs, but the general idea is that the ACF and PACF have certain [typical shapes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/autocorrelation-and-partial-autocorrelation.html) for different P and Q in ARMA(P,Q).

Comment: yes but when parameters are fixed,then this sinusoidal data is non stationary

Comment: i know this  functions,but are they effective?

Comment: @datodatuashvili, as I recall historically AR(P) processes came about in economics as an alternative to spectral analysis. The reason is that we usually don't have as much data and repeatibility as in physical sciences, so spectral analysis is hard to apply. If you have truly periodic signal, why would you want to use `pyulear` to start with? Why not FFT?

Comment: i know it,but  i am working on spectral resolution  and want to compare  AR,FFT,periodogram,wavelet

Comment: @datodatuashvili, that's a broad topic. Generally, if you deal with a periodic process with a complex spectrum such as audio recording, in my opinion, Yule-Walker spectrogram is not going to be as good as FFT. I use it in economic series analysis in frequency domain, and they work very well. We tend to have a few of oddly placed frequencies, and our series are finite -- good conditions for YW method to work, in my opinion.

Comment: that means that if we have frequencies like 30.5 and 30.9  AR  method  may not be good to resolve this  frequencies?

Comment: what about wavelet?

Comment: @datodatuashvili, I don't think you can make a general statement like that. The resolution would depend on how many lags you have, length of the series etc.

Comment: let say length of  signal  is  294,and  sampling frequency is 100,

Comment: we are allowing that frequencies could be  irrational,as well as their ratios could be irrationals